# Compactness: open cover vs. limit point

Tags: general-topology, analysis, terminology, compactness

I've been studying analysis (and some topology),
and I recently read [an article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4131.pdf) about the history of compactness.

First, the usual definition of compactness is defined via open covers:

> A set $X$ is compact if every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover.

Also, while learning about limit points,
we come with limit-point compactness (also known as the Bolzano-Weierstrass property):

> A set $X$ is limit-point compact if every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$.

I've done some reading and get that these two are equal in metric spaces;
but surely they would differ in more general topological spaces.
Some topological spaces may be compact but not limit compact, and vice versa.

So if open-cover compactness and limit-point compactness are different,
why would the open-cover definition be the "standard" definition for compactness?
In other words, what are the aspects(theorems, ideas, etc) of open-cover compactness
that makes it more useful than limit-point compactness?
For instance, in terms of generalization, arguments simply saying
that open-cover compactness is more general than limit-point compactness
seems unsatisfying to me;
I want the details about it.

I hope my questions are not too vague, and appreciate every feedback if it feels so. Thanks.

Comment: It's pretty easy to prove that a continuous function is uniformly continuous on a compact set (Heine-Cantor theorem) using the topological definitions of continuity and compactness. I haven't seen any limit-point compact proofs though.

Comment: "Some topological spaces may be compact but not limit point compact..." is not true. Compactness implies limit point compactness.

Comment: @CSquared Yeah, that's my bad. Suppose I got mixed up.

Comment: that's okay, i was just making sure it was acknowledged. great question btw!